# kubernetes: how to make sure that no user pods are run on master

Tags: kubernetes

I'm currently using Kubernetes for our staging environment - and because it is only a small one, I'm only using one node for `master` and for running my application pods on there.

When we switch over to production, there will be more than one node - at least one for master and one bigger node for the application pods. Do I have to make sure that all my pods are running on a different node than `master` or does Kubernetes take care of that automagically?

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the output of `kubectl get nodes`, you'll see something like:

```
~ kubectl get nodes
NAME                                     STATUS                     AGE       VERSION
test-master              Ready,SchedulingDisabled   23h       v1.6.0-alpha.0.1862+59cfdfb8dba60e
test-minion-group-f635   Ready                      23h       v1.6.0-alpha.0.1862+59cfdfb8dba60e
test-minion-group-fzu7   Ready                      23h       v1.6.0-alpha.0.1862+59cfdfb8dba60e
test-minion-group-vc1p   Ready                      23h       v1.6.0-alpha.0.1862+59cfdfb8dba60e
```

The `SchedulingDisabled` tag ensures that we do not schedule any pods onto that node, and each of your HA master nodes should have that by default.

It is possible to set other nodes to `SchedulingDisabled` as well by using [kubectl cordon](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_cordon/).

Answer (score 0):

you can add the --register-schedulable=false parameter to the kubelet running on your master.